# Linux: Prevent iPod Touch from charging while computer is running off battery

Tags: linux, iphone, battery, ipod-touch, charging

Is there a way to prevent an iPod Touch/iPhone from charging while my computer is running off battery power?

OS: Crunchbang Linux (Based on Debian 6)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is no.

Your motherboard and hardware would have to be able to support such a feature.  AFAIK, no motherboard supports such a feature and it is possible the USB specification prevent manufacturers from implementing such a feature.

Comment: The OS can detect when a system is running on battery power. The OS can disable certain USB ports. There's no reason the OS couldn't tie these two together.